# Redraw VC after dismissing Modal View Controller in Swift or Objective-C from Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, modalviewcontroller

I am following what I believe is the preferred pattern of allowing the user to edit content in a modal view controller. When the user taps done, the modal VC is dismissed.

However, after the modal VC is dismissed, leaving the original VC that displays the content, the content is not getting updated from core data.

The content is set in viewwillappear, however, dismissing the modal VC does not seem to trigger an update of the screen with the new data. If you do something else and come back the screen does update, so the changes are being made. The screen just isn't redrawn after the modalVC is dismissed.

How can I force an update of the presenting VC once the modal is dismissed?

Presenting VC code that sets label text from managedobject

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.myLabel.text = self.dataItem.content;//where dataItem is a managedobject in Core Data
}
```

//Here is code that launches the modalVC:

```
- (void) showEditVC:(id) sender
{  
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;    
    MyEditVC *editVC =
    [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editvc"];    
editVC.item = _dataItem;
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: editVC];   
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{ 
    }]; 
}
```

The code to dismiss the modal is in the Modal VC and triggered by a tap on DONE:

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    // Dismiss View Controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Use a delegate. Before you present the modal view controller, inject it with a delegate from the presenting view controller. And then before you dismiss the modal view controller, call that delegate to notify the presenting view controller to update its UI.